# Error al Instalar Clarity en Angular6

Tags: angular

He seguido los pasos de instalación para poder añadir clarity a mi proyecto angular6

https://v1.clarity.design/get-started

```
 npm install @clr/ui --save 
 ng add @clr/angular
 npm install @clr/icons @clr/angular @clr/ui @webcomponents/custom-elements@1.0.0 --save
```

Además de añadir en el cli.json y en el module lo necesario:

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "../node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.css",
    "../node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css",
    "styles/styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "../node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js",
    "../node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js"
  ],

-----------

import { ClarityModule } from '@clr/angular';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StartComponent,
    UserComponent,
    DetailUserComponent,
    SeccionComponent,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ClarityModule
  ],
```

Y cuando voy arrancar el proyecto el error es:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in 'D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\@angular\platform-browser'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@clr/angular/fesm5/clr-angular.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in 'D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@clr\angular\fesm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations/browser' in 'D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\@angular\platform-browser'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/filters.d.ts (14,33): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/filters.d.ts (26,25): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/filters.d.ts (30,19): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/filters.d.ts (37,52): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/sort.d.ts (4,29): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/sort.d.ts (4,31): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/sort.d.ts (22,33): Generic type 'Sort<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/utils/datagrid-filter-registrar.d.ts (4,68): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/utils/datagrid-filter-registrar.d.ts (6,26): Generic type 'FiltersProvider<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-column.d.ts (9,42): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-column.d.ts (9,44): Type parameter name cannot
be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-column.d.ts (9,84): Generic type 'DatagridStringFilterImpl<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-column.d.ts (12,24): Generic type 'Sort<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-column.d.ts (12,42): Generic type 'FiltersProvider<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/items.d.ts (6,30): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/items.d.ts (6,32): Type parameter name cannot
be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/items.d.ts (10,27): Generic type 'FiltersProvider<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/items.d.ts (10,54): Generic type 'Sort<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-items.d.ts (15,92): Generic type 'Items<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-placeholder.d.ts (2,47): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-placeholder.d.ts (2,49): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-placeholder.d.ts (4,24): Generic type 'Items<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/selection.d.ts (9,34): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/selection.d.ts (9,36): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/selection.d.ts (15,25): Generic type 'Items<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/selection.d.ts (15,45): Generic type 'FiltersProvider<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-row.d.ts (11,39): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-row.d.ts (11,41): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-row.d.ts (12,16): Generic type 'Selection<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-row.d.ts (31,28): Generic type 'Selection<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/interfaces/state.interface.d.ts (2,46): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/interfaces/state.interface.d.ts (2,48): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/state.provider.d.ts (15,26): Generic type 'FiltersProvider<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/state.provider.d.ts (15,52): Generic type 'Sort<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/state.provider.d.ts (19,24): Generic type 'ClrDatagridStateInterface<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/state.provider.d.ts (20,21): Generic type 'ClrDatagridStateInterface<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid.d.ts (16,36): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid.d.ts (16,38): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid.d.ts (19,12): Generic type 'Items<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid.d.ts (21,16): Generic type 'Selection<T, any>'
requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid.d.ts (28,98): Generic type 'Items<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid.d.ts (28,156): Generic type 'Selection<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid.d.ts (37,27): Generic type 'ClrDatagridStateInterface<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid.d.ts (71,18): Generic type 'ClrDatagridPlaceholder<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid.d.ts (75,24): Generic type 'ClrDatagridColumn<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid.d.ts (81,21): Generic type 'ClrDatagridRow<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/interfaces/filter.interface.d.ts (2,52): Type parameter
name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-filter.d.ts (14,42): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-filter.d.ts (14,44): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-filter.d.ts (14,84): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-filter.d.ts (16,27): Generic type 'FiltersProvider<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-filter.d.ts (26,19): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-filter.d.ts (26,71): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-row-detail.d.ts (13,45): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-row-detail.d.ts (13,47): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-row-detail.d.ts (14,16): Generic type 'Selection<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-row-detail.d.ts (20,28): Generic type 'Selection<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-footer.d.ts (5,42): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-footer.d.ts (5,44): Type parameter name cannot
be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-footer.d.ts (6,16): Generic type 'Selection<T,
any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-footer.d.ts (9,28): Generic type 'Selection<T,
any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter.d.ts (9,45): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter.d.ts (9,47): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter.d.ts (9,87): Generic type 'DatagridStringFilterImpl<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter.d.ts (11,26): Generic type 'FiltersProvider<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter.d.ts (15,83): Generic type 'DatagridStringFilterImpl<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter.d.ts (27,22): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilter<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-property-string-filter.d.ts (2,53): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-property-string-filter.d.ts (2,55): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/comparators/datagrid-property-comparator.d.ts (2,51): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/comparators/datagrid-property-comparator.d.ts (2,53): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/forms/common/providers/layout.service.d.ts (2,16): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/forms/common/providers/layout.service.d.ts (3,18): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/forms/common/providers/layout.service.d.ts (4,15): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/layout/vertical-nav/vertical-nav-group.d.ts (1,32): Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/modal/modal.d.ts (1,32): Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/utils/animations/collapse/collapse.d.ts (1,35): Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/utils/animations/fade/fade.d.ts (1,35): Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/utils/animations/fade-slide/fade-slide.d.ts (1,35): Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/utils/animations/slide/slide.d.ts (1,35): Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-items-trackby.d.ts (3,48): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-items-trackby.d.ts (3,50): Type parameter name
cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-items-trackby.d.ts (5,25): Generic type 'Items<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/render/main-renderer.d.ts (11,45): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/render/main-renderer.d.ts (11,47): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/render/main-renderer.d.ts (19,60): Generic type 'Items<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/render/main-renderer.d.ts (21,24): Generic type 'ClrDatagridColumn<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/popover/common/popover-host-anchor.token.d.ts (2,58): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_renderer.d.ts (1,53): Cannot find module '@angular/animations/browser'.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_builder.d.ts (8,106): Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts (1,233): Cannot find module '@angular/animations/browser'.
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/clr-angular.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/src/app/app.module.ts
    at syntaxError (D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:240:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (D:\PruebaTestingAngular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:493:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/interfaces/filter.interface.d.ts (2,50): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/interfaces/filter.interface.d.ts (7,20): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter-impl.d.ts (4,49): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter-impl.d.ts (4,51): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter-impl.d.ts (4,67): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter-impl.d.ts (37,19): Generic type 'ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S, any>' requires 3 type argument(s).
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/filters.d.ts (5,40): ',' expected.
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/providers/filters.d.ts (5,42): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
ERROR in D:/PruebaTestingAngular/node_modules/@clr/angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-hideable-column.d.ts (55,94): Generic type 'ClrDatagridColumn<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Parece que te falta la dependencia `@angular/animations`. ¿Has probado a instalarla?

Comment: Me limité a poner los comandos de la web, por mi cuenta no he instalado nada.